# Is short-circuit evaluation safe in my case?

Tags: c++

I have a simple condition that looks like this :

```
if (k==0 && f())
```

f has side effects and must not be called if k is different from 0. Can I rely on boolean short-circuits so that the compiler never calls f ? Of course, I could haved moved the if to the outside to guarantee f is never called when k != 0, but this is shorter.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that when k != 0, f will never be called in the condition ?

Comment: How about putting the check for `k` into `f()`  (or even `g()`);  then not only do you protect yourself from calling `f()` by mistake; but you also make the if statement a lot easier to read

Comment: @user463035818 (IMHO) if someone editing the code is not aware of short-circuit evaluation, then they should not be editing the code in the first place as they are not qualified to do so. I completely agree with writing code in the way that makes it most readable, but I do *not* agree that mangling a perfectly readable expression just to please incompetents is a good idea.

Comment: @Aaa Bbb    Yes, it's guaranteed that f() will not get called if k!=0.

Comment: @JesperJuhl you made me think and I deleted that comment, because it really is going into the wrong direction

Answer (score 3):

> ### 8.14 Logical AND operator [[expr.log.and](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.log.and)]
>
> 1. The && operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both contextually converted to bool (Clause 7). The result is true if both operands are true and false otherwise. Unlike &, && guarantees left-to-right evaluation: *the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand is false.*

So, if `k` is not equal to `0`, a conformant compiler will not call `f`.

Comment: when you give a quote you should give reference to the source (even if it is kinda obvious)

Comment: @user463035818 my bad, will try to be more accurate in the future.